# ASP/MySQL interaction

Tags: mysql, asp.net

If I run:

---

### SELECT `id_tara`,`Donation_Type_TARA`, `Donation_Date_TARA` FROM `tara_answers`  WHERE Donation_Made_TARA =1 AND test_data IS NULL

on MySQL I get:

[image: From MySQL Direct]

If I run:

---

SELECT `id_tara`, `Donation_Type_TARA`,`Donation_Date_TARA` FROM `tara_answers` WHERE Donation_Made_TARA =1 AND test_data IS NULL

---

under ASP I get:

[image: From ASP]

I have tried everything to get the "TO" and "O" types to show up - and for the Data to show up.

Here is the ASP line:

```
     Response.Write(objRec("id_tara") & "   " & objRec("Donation_Type_TARA") & "   " & objRec("Donation_Date_TARA") & "<br />")
```

I checked the structure for Donation_Type_TARA it's Varchar(2), Null, utf8_unicode_ci. For the date it's Date.

I've run out of things to check. Thaks. Rick

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Open statement was above the SQL statement. Thus it was opening a different SQL statement which had an error in it. Sorry to have taken your time. Rick